# What happens to your Facebook account when you die?

Tags: facebook, account-management

If a Facebook user dies, what happens to their Facebook account? Is it deleted after a certain period? Should their friends or relatives inform Facebook that they are dead?

Comment: I don't see any loss in viewing the profile in friend list who is dead. Al least, it gives me a small opportunity to memorize him/her. My perception.........

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can report this to Facebook requesting that they remove the account or memorialize the account.

From Facebook FAQ:

> **How do I report a deceased user or an account that needs to be
>   memorialized and deactivated or
>   deleted?**
>
> Memorializing the account:
>
> Please report [this information here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased) so
>   that we can memorialize this person’s
>   account. Memorializing the account
>   restricts profile access to confirmed
>   friends only. Please note that in
>   order to protect the privacy of the
>   deceased user, we cannot provide login
>   information for the account to anyone.
>   We do honor requests from close family
>   members to close the account
>   completely.
>
> Removing the account:
>
> Immediate family
>   members may request the removal of a
>   loved one’s account. This will
>   completely remove the account from
>   Facebook so that no one can view it.
>   We will not restore the account or
>   provide information on its content
>   unless required by law. If you are
>   requesting a removal and are not an
>   immediate family member of the
>   deceased, your request will not be
>   processed, but the account will be
>   memorialized.
>
> To make a request to memorialize or
>   remove a profile, please do so [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased).
>   If you have a special request
>   regarding a deceased user's account,
>   please use this form. Please note that
>   [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=memorialize_special_requests) is only to be used for
>   accounts that have already been
>   memorialized.

[The Facebook FAQ page can be found here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=13941)

Comment: It's helpful to friends-of-friends of the person if you do this reasonably soon after the person dies. Having facebook suggest you might like to become friends with someone who you've recently learnt has died is a little unnerving.

Answer (score 14):

The account can be memorialised;

> When an account is memorialized, we also set privacy so that only confirmed friends can see the profile or locate it in search. We try to protect the deceased's privacy by removing sensitive information such as contact information and status updates. Memorializing an account also prevents anyone from logging into it in the future, while still enabling friends and family to leave posts on the profile Wall in remembrance.

http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=163091042130

http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=842

Answer (score 12):

When my cousin died, the account was memorialized, meaning that the Wall is left open for comments. Facebook has [a page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=842) about the process.

> When a user passes away, we memorialize their account to protect their privacy. Memorializing an account sets the account privacy so that only confirmed friends can see the profile or locate it in search. The Wall remains, so friends and family can leave posts in remembrance. Memorializing an account also prevents anyone from logging into the account.

Answer (score 6):

**As of September 22, 2015**

If you passed away you have 2 options, and actually you can tell it to Facebook in advance by going to the Facebook settings then security

1. request for memorialization upon death
2. request for account deletion upon death

[image]

Facebook has a form for deceased person namely `Special Request for Deceased Person's Account`, [see the form here](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/228813257197480).

Legacy contact allows them to

1. Write a pinned post for your profile (ex: to share a final message
       on your behalf or provide information about a memorial service)
2. Respond to new friend requests (ex: old friends or family members
       who weren't yet on Facebook)
3. Update your profile picture and cover
       photo

Your legacy contact can't:

1. Log into your account
2. Remove or change past posts, photos and other things shared on your
   Timeline
3. Read messages you've sent to other friends
4. Remove any of your friends

Answer (score 3):

Facebook allows you memorialise or deactivate the Facebook account. Taking action in relation to the deceased person's Facebook account as quickly as possible is highly recommended.  You can close your account by using a service like enclosure.com.au (which closes all of the person's social networking accounts) or by going straight to Facebook.