# Memorializing a Facebook account requires its URL, which I don't know or have

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to your Facebook account when you die?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/what-happens-to-your-facebook-account-when-you-die)

How can I get a Facebook account memorialized when I don't know the URL of the account page?

My fiancé passed away in October.  Two weeks later I went to view his page and found it was gone.  I want the page memorialized, [but the form to memorialize and account asks for his URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/what-happens-to-your-facebook-account-when-you-die) at the following field:

> **Web address (URL) of the profile you would like to report:**
>   Please copy and paste the web address (URL) of his/her profile.

I don't have that.  I am very distraught as I have not only lost him, but our memories together.

How do I contact Facebook, other than the form because I don't have his original URL, and ask to have his account memorialized? Or how can I find out what the account URL was?

Comment: If you have browser history dating that far back, you might use that to discover what the URL was.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is https://www.facebook.com/username if he had a Facebook username or a username@facebook.com email address (replace username with his username), or https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=### otherwise (replace ### with his numeric user id).  If you do not know his username or id, you may be able to find it in some old Facebook email notifications if you still have any in your archived mail.  For example, about a week before his last birthday you may have received a notification from Facebook that his birthday was coming up.  His name should be a blue link and if you hover over it the link should include id=### (among other things), where ### is his Facebook user id.

It is my understanding that Facebook will not delete the account of a deceased user unless specifically requested by a verified immediate family member.  So if the account has been deleted then you may want to check with anyone else who may have requested this before contacting Facebook.  I would imagine that Facebook would be reluctant to take any further action if there is evidence of a family dispute.