# Keeping your Facebook profile after death

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to your Facebook account when you die?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/what-happens-to-your-facebook-account-when-you-die)

Ok, avoiding easy jokes, I do want my profile and all my photos, everything, to be publicy available when I die.

I think that we are the first generation that could hope to live (digitally) forever and I think that Facebook is a perfect candidate to be my digital grave.

Is this possible?

Comment: As long as their servers run, then I guess so.

Comment: @nK0de yes but what i mean is that my facebook page should also show that i'm dead

Comment: [What happens to your Facebook account when you die?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11436/88)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [ifidie](http://ifidie.net/) program, which will let you post a message or video on your facebook after you die (it asks three of your friends to verify you are dead).

Other people can also '[memorialize](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased)' your profile (puts it in a special, you are dead, state).