# Death in the Family

Tags: facebook

My son has taken his own life. There was no note and none of his friends (he had many) can answer why. Is it possible to access his Facebook account? There might be some hint as to his mind frame. I know he was on Facebook an hour before he took his life.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to your Facebook account when you die?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/what-happens-to-your-facebook-account-when-you-die)

Comment: maybe irrelevant but i'm so sorry to hear about this, my prayers are with you.

Comment: The linked question is not quite a duplicate. That one is just about what happens to the account, this one is about accessing the account.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the Facebook [FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/150486848354038/):

> In order to protect the privacy of the deceased person, we cannot
>   provide login information for the account.

So it looks like Facebook won't facilitate access. Unless there is a legal route to gaining access, you're best chance may be if you can get access to the email account (or possibly mobile phone) associated with the Facebook account. Then you can go through the password reset process to gain access.